# Connecting java to swift using MQTT

Tags: java, swift, mqtt

I am trying to implement Moscapsule in my swift project having java on the server side. I am not getting the proper flow on how to connect from swift to java Here is a snippet on client code in java and swift code which was mentioned in the documentation of Moscapsule 
https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule

Server code:

```
 MqttClient client;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/connect")
public void connect(){
    try {
          client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883", "pahomqttpublish1");
          client.connect();
          MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
          message.setPayload("A single message".getBytes());
          client.publish("pahodemo/test", message);
          client.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Swift Code:

```
let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "manu992", host: "192.168.2.164", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)

    mqttConfig.onPublishCallback = { messageId in
        NSLog("published (mid=\(messageId))")
    }

    mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
        NSLog("MQTT Message received: payload=\(mqttMessage.payloadString)")
    }

    // create new MQTT Connection
    let mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig)

    // publish and subscribe
    mqttClient.publishString("message", topic: "pahodemo/test", qos: 2, retain: false)
    mqttClient.subscribe("pahodemo/test", qos: 2)

    // disconnect
            mqttClient.disconnect()
```

This is the response i am getting

```
2015-09-15 17:37:04.257 mqttSwift[8205:544857] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client manu992 sending CONNECT
2015-09-15 17:37:04.259 mqttSwift[8205:544858] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client manu992 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: pahodemo/test, QoS: 2)
2015-09-15 17:37:04.259 mqttSwift[8205:544856] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client manu992 sending PUBLISH (d0, q2, r0, m2, 'pahodemo/test', ... (7 bytes))
2015-09-15 17:37:04.260 mqttSwift[8205:544857] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client manu992 sending DISCONNECT
```

Comment: What's your question? It looks like you're able to make a connection in Swift just fine...

Comment: is there any way to make a offline message queue using this if the user has not yet subscribed any channel